# How to init a WKWebView without using existing cookies

Tags: ios, cookies, webkit, wkwebview

I'm using some `WKWebView`s within my apps.
Basically, I have a first `WKWebView` and the user should be able to create another one `WKWebView` without any cookies so he/she wouldn't be logged in any account he logged in before on the first `WKWebView`.
It's like an incognito browsing mode.

But I can't see anything that would allow me to do that with `WKWebView`.
I think it's not possible as this bug suggests : 
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140191

But maybe someone found a workaround ?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading Apple's documentation, I finally got it to work.

I just initialise the `WKWebView` with a non-persistent `WKWebsiteDataStore` like that :

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistentDataStore()
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: configuration)
```